# JavaFX _ Как выбрать RadioButton в новой Сцене

Tags: javafx

У меня есть много сцен, в которых везде присутствует toogleGroup с RadioButton. Чтобы в каждую сцену не запихивать обработчик эти RadioButton, я выделил его в отдельный контроллер. (Да, по умолчанию, я уже сделал, что в каждой из сцен был свой обработчик всех кнопок и оно прекрасно работало, но это было слишком загромождено лишним кодом)

Вопрос, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии какой-либо из RadioButton на Stage открывалась новая Scene с уже нажатой RadioButton?

У меня есть Stage, которая запускается вот так :

```
public class Main extends Application {



Stage stage;
Scene scene;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MVC/View/check.fxml"));
    scene = new Scene(root);

    stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setTitle("Hello People");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();


}}
```

Собственно  toogle.fxml

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER" fillHeight="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="700.0"
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MVC.Controller.ControllerToogle">
<children>
    <RadioButton fx:id="btnCheck" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false"
                 onAction="#radioButtonChanged" text="Проверить"
                 textAlignment="CENTER" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup" >
        <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
        </HBox.margin>
        <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="toggleGroup"/>
        </toggleGroup>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton fx:id="btnDelete" contentDisplay="CENTER" focusTraversable="false"
                 mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonChanged" text="Удалить"
                 textAlignment="CENTER" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup">
        <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
        </HBox.margin>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton fx:id="btnCreate" contentDisplay="CENTER" focusTraversable="false"
                 mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonChanged" text="Создать"
                 textAlignment="CENTER" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup">
        <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
        </HBox.margin>
    </RadioButton>
</children>
```

И, допустим, check.fxml, которая является 1 из многих сцен

```
<children>

    <fx:include source="toogle.fxml"></fx:include>

    <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" fillHeight="false" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="20.0">
        <children>
            <TextField fx:id="inputField" alignment="CENTER" focusTraversable="false" maxHeight="-Infinity"
                       maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="250.0">
                <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
                </HBox.margin>
            </TextField>
            <TextArea fx:id="outputField" editable="false" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="250.0" snapToPixel="false">
                <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
                </HBox.margin>
            </TextArea>
        </children>
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
        </padding>
    </HBox>


    <Button fx:id="btnDoIt" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false"
            onAction="#processButton" textAlignment="CENTER">

        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </Button>

</children>
```

Сейчас, только через такие сложные извращения в контроллере, я смог получить доступ к RadioButton

```
public class ControllerToogle {

@FXML
private ToggleGroup toggleGroup;
@FXML
private TextField inputField;
@FXML
private RadioButton btnCheck;
@FXML
private RadioButton btnDelete;
@FXML
private RadioButton btnCreate;


@FXML
public void radioButtonChanged(ActionEvent actionEvent) {


    Stage stageTheEventSourceNodeBelongs = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    RadioButton pressedRadioButton = (RadioButton) toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle();

    try {
        if (pressedRadioButton.getId().equals("btnCheck")) {
            stageTheEventSourceNodeBelongs.setScene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MVC/View/check.fxml")));

        } else if (pressedRadioButton.getId().equals("btnDelete")) {
            stageTheEventSourceNodeBelongs.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MVC/View/delete.fxml"))));

        } else if (pressedRadioButton.getId().equals("btnCreate")) {
            stageTheEventSourceNodeBelongs.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MVC/View/create.fxml"))));
        }

        VBox vbox = (VBox) stageTheEventSourceNodeBelongs.getScene().getRoot();
        HBox hbox = (HBox) vbox.getChildren().get(0);
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) hbox.getChildren().get(1);
        button.setSelected(true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Наиболее правильное (если я верно понял описание): перестроить дизайн. Использовать одну сцену, на которой есть этот набор кнопок `RadioButton`. И на основании действий с этой кнопкой менять часть сцены.
2. Вынести ваш `HBox` с `RadioButton` в отдельный самостоятельный компонент. Таким образом контролеры будут иметь одну `@FXML private MyPanel myPanel;`. Добавляете метод `getMyPanel`, который в свою очередь предоставляет доступ к конкретным `RadioButton`. И после создания сцены через эти методы выделяете необходимую вам кнопку. Про создание таких компонентов информации много, хороший пример в [этом посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434787/how-to-create-custom-components-in-javafx-2-0-using-fxml)
3. Этот вариант не дает возможности получить доступ к конкретной кнопке определенной сцены, но позволяет использовать единый обработчик (может быть и пригодится):

Пример общего обработчика для всех сцен, в рамках одного `Stage`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton("1");
        RadioButton radioButton1 = new RadioButton("2");
        RadioButton radioButton2 = new RadioButton("3");

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        toggleGroup.getToggles().addAll(radioButton, radioButton1, radioButton2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(radioButton, radioButton1, radioButton2));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            if (event.getTarget() instanceof RadioButton) {
                // Кнопка которая была выделена
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) event.getTarget();
                System.out.println(rb);
            }
        });
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Добрый день. 
Спасибо за ваш развернутый комментарий.

1) Не понятно, что вы используете по сценой, Stage или Scene. Если 2, то у меня как раз и есть отдельная toogle.fxml, только с кнопками, а есть отдельные check.fxml и т.д. 


2)В принципе, у меня так и есть, в каждой дополнительной fxml, у меня есть вставка <fx:include source="toogle.fxml"></fx:include>, можно, конечно добавить туда еще fx:id="Toogle", например.


3) Вроде бы не подходит, но вариант интересный, я его, наверное, применю для таблицы

Comment: 1) Сцена это `Scene`. В вашем вопросе вы говорили что имеется много сцен, т.е. один `Stage` и много `Scene` - в описанной задаче в этом нет смысла, поэтому и предложил перестроить дизайн. 2) `include fxml` просто вставляет исходники, но не переносит функционал, поэтому и приходится в контроллере описывать все кнопки и методы. Предложенный вариант позволил бы писать в `fxml` файле: `import my.package.MyPanel; ... <children><MyPanel fx:id="myPanel"/></children>` и использовать в контроллере как `@FXML private MyPanel myPanel;`